# Check if cell contains Non-Alpha characters in Excel

Tags: excel-2013

Is there a Non-VBA way to check Col B and Col C to see if they contains any characters that are Non-Alpha? Just to clarify by Non-Alpha I mean anything not part of the alphabet(case insensitive).

Col B and Col C is a list of First and Last Names. Some of these names have symbols or numbers in them through bad data entry. I am trying to find all the ones that need to be fixed. So I need to find the ones that contain ***ANYTHING*** that is not a letter.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is a "weird" but simple and generic answer.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))
```

- This formula returns `#VALUE!` error if A1 contains any non-letter characters, number if A1 contains only letters, or `#REF!` error if A1 is blank.
- You can enclose this formula in an `ISNUMBER` or `ISERR` to convert this to a TRUE/FALSE value.
- Replace the `SEARCH` with a `FIND` to make it case sensitive. Using `FIND` will ensure wildcard characters "?~*" are identified as non-letter characters.
- You can put any character in the `"abc...xyz"` string. This makes it easy to test of alphanumeric, or common punctuations, etc.

The `"1:"&LEN(A1)` means that starting from the first letter, all the way to the last letter will be checked. Changing that to `"2:"&(LEN(A1)-1)` will not check the first and last letters.

Comment: This works really quite well. And your explanation of how it works is very much appreciated. I do have one further question. How would I allow it to accept spaces? The idea being that the cell value of "Chad" would be good, "Chad1" would not be good, and "O Neal" would be good.

Comment: @ChadPortman Put a space in the `"abc...xyz"` string. as in `" abc...xyz"`.

Comment: That was simple should have tried that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use 26 nested `SUBSTITUTE`s to remove all alphabetic characters from the text.

If anything is left over, the cell contains non-alpha characters.

And thanks to @RaGe for pointing out that you need to check for empty cells as well:

```
=AND(ISTEXT(A2),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A2),"a",),"b",),"c",),"d",),"e",),"f",),"g",),"h",),"i",),"j",),"k",),"l",),"m",),"n",),"o",),"p",),"q",),"r",),"s",),"t",),"u",),"v",),"w",),"x",),"y",),"z",) = "")
```

[image]

Comment: Just be careful that this returns TRUE for a empty cell as well

Comment: Wow that is so strange that works. I feel like there has to be a more efficient way to do than 26 nested formulas but it does work. Thanks for that. I guess I will use this for now until I can find something more streamline.

Comment: @nights, it wasn't until Roobie posted a much more elegant solution : )