# Identify Special Characters

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I need to identify cells that have certain special characters (example: !,.=]\')  and mark them with a color.

The column can only contain numbers (0-9), letters (a-z), as caps (A-Z) and hyphen (-).

Example:[image]

Comment: Regex -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: It seems that beside the letters and digits, the cells can have `-`, too, right?

Comment: It can also be done without VBA macro with Conditional Formating formula http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855647/check-if-cell-contains-non-alpha-characters-in-excel

Comment: why a downvote? can someone explain please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex for this task.

A useful regex construct here is a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated): you use `[^...]` and insert the ranges you do not want to match in there. So, to match a char other than ASCII letters, digits, and a hyphen, use `[^a-zA-Z0-9-]`.

And use it like

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[^a-z0-9-]"
Dim regEx As Object

Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regEx.Global = True
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Pattern = strPattern

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C:C") ' Define your own range here
    If strPattern <> "" Then              ' If the cell is not empty
        If regEx.Test(cell.Value) Then    ' Check if there is a match
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6  ' If yes, change the background color
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The above code works fine.. I need the special characters count

Comment: @VinothNarayan Is it a new question? Actually, it is too easy: instead of the whole `For Each` block, just use `Set ms = regEx.Execute(cell.Value)` and then use `ms.Count`.

Answer (score 4):

*Without regex:*

This macro processes column **B**:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range, s As String
    Dim i As Long, L As Long

    Set rng = Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            s = Replace(r.Text, "-", "")
            L = Len(s)
            For i = 1 To L
                If Not Mid(s, i, 1) Like "[0-9a-zA-Z]" Then
                    r.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

It will accept only numerals, upper and lower case letters, and the dash.

Comment: The downvotes on your answers confuse me so I +1 as I don't see any issue. Downvoters please give any hint as to why this answer not useful.

Comment: @Slai  Thee may be a bug in there somewhere.............I will re-examine the answer.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, thanks for your time

Comment: @Deluq I usually get downvotes if I post code with no explanation....thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Yeah, actually I liked your answer without regex